# How to draw a specific object with a different projection than other objects?

Tags: java, java-3d

So I haven't been able to find anything on this anywhere: I'm using Java3D to create an environment for my users. I'd like to put a 3D display of the X, Y, and Z axis in the corner that rotates as they rotate their view. Unfortunately, it needs to be in the corner instead of right in the center. This means that with the normal View projection (PERSPECTIVE_PROJECTION), the axis don't line up quite right and it looks really, really awkward. Using PARALLEL_PROJECTION instead fixes the awkward axis display, but then I can't view the world properly because it doesn't let me zoom anymore. Is there any way to tell the renderer to use PARALLEL_PROJECTION specifically for the axis display and PERSPECTIVE_PROJECTION on all other objects? Or is there another way around this problem I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

Simply for better understanding of the Java3D concepts I recommend you to read [this](http://www.sdsc.edu/~nadeau/Courses/Siggraph99/) tutorial. It helps me very much